# Handling POST request on a GET route (express.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request

I am new to express and node together and seem to be stuck, with what seems to be, a simple issue. I have an API route that uses `GET`. Route:

```
app.get('/api/v1/all', getAllWords);
```

Then inside of the `getAllWords` callback function, I want to check if the request that was sent was of `GET` or `POST`. This is the code I have to check the request method:

```
function getAllWords(request, response) {
   let reply;
   if (request.method === 'GET') {
      console.log('This was a GET request');
      // handle GET here...
   }
   if (request.method === 'POST') {
      console.log('This was a POST request');
      reply = {
          "msg": "HTTP Method not allowed"
      };
      response.send(reply)
   }
}
```

When I use Postman to send off a `GET` request it works just fine. But when sending a `POST` request I get the generic express.js "*Cannot POST /api/v1/all*".

[image: Postman screenshot]

Why did it the `response.send(reply)` not work for the `POST` method?

Comment: _"Why did it the response.send(reply) not work for the POST method?"_ - because it doesn't get this far. `Cannot POST /api/v1/all` tells you all you need to know - you did not configure your app to handle a POST request on this route ... so it simply _doesn't_.

Answer (score 1):

`app.get(...)` define endpoint that only matches with GET method. If you want to handle POST method you must supply seperate middleware in `app.post(...)`

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `app.all(...)` to handle both `GET` and `POST` requests but it also accepts other kind of requests such as `PUT` and `DELETE`. I prefer separating the `GET`and `POST` request though.